# The bubble image arrow is always on the right direction. How to change green bubbles' arrow direction to left?

Tags: ios, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

[image]

In my JSQMessagesViewController, when I load text message bubbles, the arrow direction is always right side.
How to change arrow direction to left for green bubbles??

My Code:

```
@interface AckChatViewController (){

    JSQMessagesBubbleImage *outgoingBubbleImageView;
    JSQMessagesBubbleImage *incomingBubbleImageView;

    JSQMessagesAvatarImage *currentUserAvatar, *friendAvatar;
    NSMutableArray *messages;
}

@end
```

@implementation AckChatViewController

## pragma mark - life cycle methods

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
    //initial things for JSQMessageViewController
    [self setupBubbles];
    messages = [NSMutableArray new];

    AllUserDetailsModel *temp = [[AllUserDetailsModel alloc] initWithDictionary:[Neo_Constants getSavedDataFromUserDafaults:USER_INFO_DICTIONARY]];

    self.senderId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp.user_id];

    self.senderDisplayName = @"";

    self.automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage = YES;

    //remove attachment button
    self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem = nil;

    currentUserAvatar = [JSQMessagesAvatarImage avatarImageWithPlaceholder: [self cropAvatarImages:[UIImage imageNamed:[self defaultImageForGender:temp.userDetails.gender]]]];

    friendAvatar = [JSQMessagesAvatarImage avatarImageWithPlaceholder: [self cropAvatarImages:[UIImage imageNamed:[self defaultImageForGender:self.friendUserDetails.userDetails.gender]]]];

    NSString *imageUrlString = temp.userDetails.profile_pic;

    [self avatarImagesForUrlString:imageUrlString andOnCompletion:^(UIImage *image) {

        if(image){
            currentUserAvatar.avatarImage = image;
        }
    }];

    [self avatarImagesForUrlString:self.friendUserDetails.userDetails.profile_pic andOnCompletion:^(UIImage *image) {

        if(image){
            friendAvatar.avatarImage = image;
        }
    }];

    //set profile pic and name on navigation bar
    [self setNavigationBarTitleView];

    [self loadPreviousChatWithPageCount:0];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

## pragma mark - JSQ Setups

```
-(void)setupBubbles{

    JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory *bubbleImageFactory = [JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory new];

    outgoingBubbleImageView = [bubbleImageFactory outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor]];

    incomingBubbleImageView = [bubbleImageFactory outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor jsq_messageBubbleGreenColor]];

}
```

## pragma mark Collection view JSQ

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return messages.count;
}

-(id<JSQMessageData>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return messages[indexPath.item];
}

-(id<JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    JSQMessage *message = messages[indexPath.item];

    if([message.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]){

        return outgoingBubbleImageView;

    }else{

        return incomingBubbleImageView;

    }

}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *cell = (JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *)[super collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    JSQMessage *message = messages[indexPath.item];
    if([message.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]){

        [cell.textView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }else{

        [cell.textView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }

    return cell;
}

-(id<JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    JSQMessage *message = messages[indexPath.item];

    if([message.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]){

        return currentUserAvatar;
    }else{

        return friendAvatar;
    }
}

-(void)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView header:(JSQMessagesLoadEarlierHeaderView *)headerView didTapLoadEarlierMessagesButton:(UIButton *)sender{


}

//time stamp
-(NSAttributedString *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView attributedTextForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return nil;

}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView layout:(JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout heightForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 0;
}

#pragma mark - private functions
-(NSString *)defaultImageForGender:(NSString *)gender{

    if([gender isEqualToString:@"M"] || [gender isEqualToString:@""]){
        return @"no_image_male";
    }else{
        return @"no_image_female";
    }
}

-(void)setNavigationBarTitleView{

    UIView *whole = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 100, 100)];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 20, 50, 50)];

    [imageView.layer setCornerRadius:25.0f];
    [imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

    if([self.friendUserDetails.userDetails.profile_pic isEqualToString:@""] || [self.friendUserDetails.userDetails.profile_pic isEqual:[NSNull null]]){

        if([self.friendUserDetails.userDetails.gender isEqualToString:@"M"]){
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image_male"]];
        }else{
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image_female"]];
        }
    }else{

        [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.friendUserDetails.userDetails.profile_pic]];
    }


    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 50)];
    [nameLabel setText:self.friendUserDetails.userDetails.fname];

    [whole addSubview:nameLabel];
    [whole addSubview:imageView];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = whole;
}

#pragma mark - Avtar images area

-(void)avatarImagesForUrlString:(NSString *)urlString andOnCompletion:(void(^)(UIImage *image))completion{

    if([urlString isEqualToString:@""] || [urlString isEqual:[NSNull null]]){

        completion(nil);

    }else{

        [[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] options:0 progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {

            completion ([self cropAvatarImages:image]);
        }];
    }
}

-(UIImage *)cropAvatarImages:(UIImage *)image{

    if(image){
        return [JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory circularAvatarImage:image withDiameter:48];
    }else{
        if([self.friendUserDetails.userDetails.gender isEqualToString:@"M"]){
            return [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image_male"];
        }else{
            return [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image_female"];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - API calls

-(void)loadPreviousChatWithPageCount:(int)count{

    [API fetchChatListOfUserWithParams:paramsDict andOnCompletion:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error){

        if (!error) {

            if ([[result objectForKey:@"status"] intValue]==1) {

                NSArray *conversation_data = [result objectForKey:@"conversation_data"];
                [messages removeAllObjects];
                [conversation_data enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop){

                    JSQMessage *jsqMsg = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:obj[@"sender_id"] senderDisplayName:@"" date:obj[@"sent_date"] text:obj[@"message_content"]];

                    [messages insertObject:jsqMsg atIndex:idx];

                }];
                [self.collectionView reloadData];

            }else{
               [Neo_Constants showAlert:@"Error" Message:[result objectForKey:@"message"]];
            }

        }else{
            [Neo_Constants showAlert:@"Error" Message:[error localizedDescription]];
        }


    }];

}

-(void)didPressSendButton:(UIButton *)button withMessageText:(NSString *)text senderId:(NSString *)senderId senderDisplayName:(NSString *)senderDisplayName date:(NSDate *)date{

    //    [JSQSystemSoundPlayer jsq_playMessageSentSound];

    [API sendMessageFromUserWithParams:paramsDict andOnCompletion:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error){

        if (!error) {

            if ([[result objectForKey:@"status"] intValue]==1) {

                [self loadPreviousChatWithPageCount:0];
                [self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView setText:@""];

            }else{
                [Neo_Constants showAlert:@"Error" Message:[result objectForKey:@"message"]];
            }

        }else{
            [Neo_Constants showAlert:@"Error" Message:[error localizedDescription]];
        }


    }];

}

@end
```

Comment: thanks for edit question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is in this  code  you initialise outgoing and incomming with the same method  which is

```
outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor
```

try incoming with

```
incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor
```

and outgoing  with  this

```
outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor
```

this correct one

```
-(void)setupBubbles{
    JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory *bubbleImageFactory = [JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory new];

    outgoingBubbleImageView = [bubbleImageFactory outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor]];

    incomingBubbleImageView = [bubbleImageFactory incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor jsq_messageBubbleGreenColor]];

}
```